# how to update app database after insert data to sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

After I inserted new data to sqlite database by db browser, I want to upgrade my copied database on app. how can i do that? I changed the version number but it didn't work. Database is still looking empty.

Here's my onUpgrade method:

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Words");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyList");
        onCreate(db);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You DELETEing all data in the Words and MyList tables as DROP deletes the table. The tables are likely made again in onCreate and will be nothing in them.

If you want to keep data and change the schema then you need to ALTER the tables in onUpgrade, which could be a need to :-

1. create a new temp table with new schema, then
2. copy data from the original table then
3. rename the original table then
4. rename the temp table with the original name.

Look at [onUpgrade](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int))

If you have a replacement database, then copy into assets folder and use process to copy the database from the assets to the final location, this could be started in onUpgrade.